# No such element: Unable to locate element error while clicking on a button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new with selenium and I'm trying to write a code that will pop-up a item to sell in second hand site.
Everything works well until I'm trying to find the pop-up button.

This is how the html code in the site:

[image: snapshot]

And this is the line in my code:

```
pop_up = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[@id='bounceRatingOrderBtn']")).click()
```

I'v tried to find a solution for hours but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: Welcome! Can you share with us the link of the website?

Comment: Add sample link.

Comment: Thank you guys! 
It's an Israeli site call Yad2 and this is the link - https://www.yad2.co.il/

Answer (score 0):

Is the pop up button appears in a different frame or new window ? Check that and switch to frame or new window as required and then perform perform operation on your button.

I am not familiar with python selenium, I can give java selenium codes for frame and window switch, please understand the logic/code and find python version of code by yourself mate.

Java version of code for Frame switch -

```
driver.switchTo().frame("yournewframename");
```

Java version of code for Window switch -

```
        for(String handle:driver.getWindowHandles()) 
        {
            String windowtitle = driver.switchTo().window(handle).getTitle();
            if(windowtitle.contains("your new pagetitle"))
            {
                System.out.println("Title after switching "+driver.getTitle());
                break;  
            }
        }
```

Comment: <iframe src="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=personalAreaViewDetails&amp;CatID=3&amp;SubCatID=0&amp;OrderID=41976104" width="100%" height="1096" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
I think that this is the new frame but i can't switch to it with the src and it has no name or id, you got any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can switch to frame using index, try that.     driver.switch_to.frame(index number)

Answer (score 0):

I Think as [Partha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9717780/partha) siad the problem related to frameworks, I just add python version of switching between frameworks:

driver.switch_to.frame('find your other frame element here')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

Comment: <iframe src="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=personalAreaViewDetails&amp;CatID=3&amp;SubCatID=0&amp;OrderID=41976104" width="100%" height="1096" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
I think that this is the new frame but i can't switch to it with the src and it has no name or id, you got any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#bounceRatingOrderBtn[name='bounceRatingOrderBtn']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='bounceRatingOrderBtn' and @name='bounceRatingOrderBtn']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! when I'm trying this both using xpath and css_selecrot I'm getting an error selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
do you have any idea why? Thanks!